BMSUserErrorInvalidInput error on TriggerRestoreAsync (restore a SQL database backup to an SQL server running on a azure VM)
I am trying to restore a SQL database backup to an SQL server running on a azure VM. Barely any examples or documentation (other then non-informative auto generated stuff)
My test code is below. Everything goes fine until TriggerRestoreAsync is called. It claims the input is not correct, but what about the input is incorrect is not in the error. It references required parameters without telling what those parameters are.
Is there some help available?
Azure.RequestFailedException: ' The User input provided for the call is invalid. Please check the required inputs
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: BMSUserErrorInvalidInput
I'm using nuget packages: Azure.ResourceManager.RecoveryServicesBackup" Version="1.2.0"
        string subscriptionId = "<my subscription id>";
        string resourceGroupName = "<my resource name>";
        string vaultName = "<my recoveryvault name>";
        string fabricName = "Azure";
        string containerName = "VMAppContainer;Compute;<my resource name>;<my servername>";

  ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

        // Get subscription
        SubscriptionResource subscription = client.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}"));

        // Get resourcegroup from subscription
        ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroupName);

        // Get the recovery service vault fromm resourcegroup 
        RecoveryServicesVaultResource vault = await resourceGroup.GetRecoveryServicesVaultAsync(vaultName);

        string sourceSQLServer = "mysqlservername";
        string sourceAGName = "mssqlserver";
        string sourceDatabaseName = "mydbname";

        // Get al backup protected items in resourcegroup/
        // Todo: figure out correct filter for Name --> $"sqldatabase;{sourceAGName};{sourceDatabaseName}
        string backupProtectedItemFilter = $"backupManagementType eq '{BackupManagementType.AzureWorkload}'";
        var backupProtectedItems = resourceGroup.GetBackupProtectedItemsAsync(vaultName, backupProtectedItemFilter);

        BackupProtectedItemResource? backupProtectedItemResource = null;

        // backupProtectedItems is Pageable<> and does paging automatically
        await foreach (BackupProtectedItemResource item in backupProtectedItems)
        {
            if (item.Data.Name.ToLower() == $"sqldatabase;{sourceAGName};{sourceDatabaseName}".ToLower())
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Data.Name}, ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                backupProtectedItemResource = item;
            }

        }

        if (backupProtectedItemResource != null)
        {
            BackupRecoveryPointCollection recoveryPoints = backupProtectedItemResource.GetBackupRecoveryPoints();

            // Select the most recent restorepoint
            BackupRecoveryPointResource backupRecoveryPointResource = recoveryPoints.OrderByDescending(x => (x.Data.Properties as WorkloadSqlRecoveryPoint).RecoveryPointCreatedOn).FirstOrDefault();

            if (backupRecoveryPointResource != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"RecoveryPoint: {backupRecoveryPointResource.Id}");
                var d = (Azure.ResourceManager.RecoveryServicesBackup.Models.WorkloadSqlRecoveryPoint)backupRecoveryPointResource.Data.Properties; 
                Console.WriteLine($"RecoveryPoint CreatedOn: {d.RecoveryPointCreatedOn}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                // Get Target container
                BackupProtectionContainerResource targetBackupProtectionContainerResource = null;
                string filter = "backupManagementType eq 'AzureWorkload'";

                await foreach (BackupProtectionContainerResource item in resourceGroup.GetBackupProtectionContainersAsync(vaultName, filter: filter))
                {
                    if (item.Data.Properties is VmAppContainerProtectionContainer
                        && (item.Data.Properties as VmAppContainerProtectionContainer).FriendlyName == sourceSQLServer
                        )
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Data.Name}");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                        targetBackupProtectionContainerResource = item;
                    }

                }

                string newDatabaseName = "restoredb_" + sourceDatabaseName;

                string dataPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA";
                string logPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA";

                WorkloadSqlRestoreContent restoreContent = new WorkloadSqlRestoreContent();

                restoreContent.TargetInfo = new TargetRestoreInfo();
                restoreContent.TargetInfo.OverwriteOption = RestoreOverwriteOption.FailOnConflict;
                restoreContent.TargetInfo.ContainerId = targetBackupProtectionContainerResource!.Id;
                restoreContent.TargetInfo.DatabaseName = newDatabaseName; 

                restoreContent.RecoveryType = FileShareRecoveryType.AlternateLocation;
                restoreContent.SourceResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{sourceSQLServer.ToLower()}");

                restoreContent.TargetResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName;
                restoreContent.RecoveryMode = RecoveryMode.WorkloadRecovery;

                restoreContent.ShouldUseAlternateTargetLocation = false;
                restoreContent.AlternateDirectoryPaths.Add(new SqlDataDirectoryMapping() { MappingType = SqlDataDirectoryType.Data, SourceLogicalName = $"{sourceDatabaseName}", TargetPath = $"{dataPath}\\{newDatabaseName}.mdf" });
                restoreContent.AlternateDirectoryPaths.Add(new SqlDataDirectoryMapping() { MappingType = SqlDataDirectoryType.Log, SourceLogicalName = $"{sourceDatabaseName}_log", TargetPath = $"{logPath}\\{newDatabaseName}.ldf" });

                restoreContent.TargetVirtualMachineId = new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{sourceSQLServer.ToLower()}");




                // Start the actual restore
                var operation = await backupRecoveryPointResource.TriggerRestoreAsync(
                    WaitUntil.Started,
                    new TriggerRestoreContent(AzureLocation.WestEurope)
                    {
                        Properties = restoreContent
                    }
                    );

                BackupJobResource backupJobResource = client.GetBackupJobResource(new ResourceIdentifier(operation.Id));

                while (backupJobResource.Data.Properties.Status != "Completed" && backupJobResource.Data.Properties.Status != "Failed")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {backupJobResource.Data.Properties.Operation}, status{backupJobResource.Data.Properties.Status}, started: {backupJobResource.Data.Properties.StartOn}");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }

            }
        }

